# Find specific files and move them with smbclient

Tags: bash

```
$ find /opt/backup/test -name "*.gz" -exec smbclient -A \
/opt/backup/smbclient_authentication.txt //1.1.1.1/test -c put '{}' \;
```

There are multiple directories and other files then `*.gz` under the dir and I want to move the files found with find with smbclient. Of course, this does not work, since I am missing the last bit. Connection to the share works, and `find` works, it's just the last bit that does not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to create parameters from input stream

```
xargs find /opt/backup/test -name "*.gz" \
    | smbclient -A /opt/backup/smbclient_auth.txt //1.1.1.1/test -c put
```

If I understand correctly you want to move the files locally besides transferring the via smb. You could:

```
set -e  #<- abort on error
for f in `find -name '*.gz' -or -name '*.zip'`; do 
    smbclient -A /opt/backup/smbclient_auth.txt //1.1.1.1/test -c put "$f"
    mv "$f" ./transfered/
done
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the input. Although i cannot seem to get the actual put to work, smbclient just goes "put <filename>"

Comment: set -e  #<- abort on error
for f in `find /opt/backup/test -name '*.gz'`; do
    smbclient -A /opt/backup/smbclient_authentication.txt //1.1.1.1/test -c "put $f"
done

gives me: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID opening remote file \/opt/backup/test/asdasdas.gz

Comment: i have also tried this one:

echo '- Updating Client folder -'
smbclient -U $user%$pwd //$targetIP/$sharedDirRoot -c "cd $targetDir; lcd $linuxSourceDir; prompt off;recurse; mput *;"
echo '- Remote Client Updated -'


but mput takes all or nothing, tried with mput *.gz f.ex